# Difference between shuffling a list of integers and a list of "lists of single integer"

Tags: python, random

I am studying a randomized algorithm for the Kaczmarz algorithm which solves any linear system `Ax = b`. In the python code, I am puzzled about the way of shuffling the array:

```
import random
x = [[i] for i in range(len(Im))] # Im is some numpy array of length ~30000
random.shuffle(x)
for rows in x:
    rows=rows[0]
    '''Code using the variable "rows" to pick corresponding matrix elements'''
```

May I ask is there any reason to create `x` with each integer element wrapped in a list? I found that the above implementation seems to be equivalent to

```
import random
x = [i for i in range(len(Im))] # Im is some numpy array of length ~30000
random.shuffle(x)
for rows in x:
    '''Code using the variable "rows" to pick corresponding matrix elements'''
```

Comment: The reason to wrap something in a list is usually that you intend to modify the list -- lists are mutable, ints are not.  I don't know enough about the algorithm to know if that's relevant here, although since it just does `rows = rows[0]` to immediately lose the reference to the list and any usefulness it might have had, I suspect it is not.

Comment: Do you have a source for the first block of code? It might help provide more context.

Comment: Yes, the code is actually open-source on github: https://github.com/PBenderLux/Data-analysis/blob/master/1%20Inverse%20problems/notebooks/SANS-2D_experiment_Kaczmarz.ipynb. It is somewhere at the middle of the last cell .

Comment: I can't see a reason to wrap each integer in a list like they've done. Sometimes people make strange decisions when they code. It's not *wrong*, but it's not ideal.

Comment: I see, thanks to Samwise and Andrew

Comment: You could then golf the initializer down to `x = list(range(len(Im)))`, or alternatively use `random.sample` to give you a pre-shuffled list